# A few basic questions about mysql

Tags: mysql, transactions

teachers!

I am newly confront with mysql transactions, and some questions not clear.

1. If "dirty read", "non repeatable read" or "phantom read" happens, will the transaction successfully committed?
2. If two clients update one row at the same time, but they set different columns, will problems happen?
   How does the mysql deal with update? copy/modify/rewrite the whole row, or just change modified field separately?
3. If a write a complex statement,such as

   ```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW View_Rank AS (
       SELECT
           (
               SELECT
                   COUNT(1) + 1
               FROM
                   tb_Rank AS a
               WHERE
                   a.DId = b.DId
               AND (
                   a.Points > b.Points
                   OR (
                       a.Points = b.Points
                       AND (
                           a.PlayTime < b.PlayTime
                           OR (
                               a.PlayTime = b.PlayTime AND a.Id < b.Id
                           )
                       )
                   )
               )
           ) AS Rank,
           b.PersonId,
           b.DId
       FROM
           tb_Rank AS b
   ) ;
   ```

   Will "non repeatable read" happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In InnoDB, by default, isolation is REPEATABLE READ.  By way of locking and versioning, MySQL ensures that once you read a row (or try to read a row, and don't find it), that row cannot be changed until your transaction finishes as it takes a lock on it

2) Generally speaking, when using InnoDB your update will lock in the first transaction and the second one will wait until the lock is released and then successfully make the update.

3) Non repeatable reads are not possible in the default isolation of REPEATABLE READ, due to read locking, your transaction will have to wait.

Lots of information to read here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-transaction-model.html